# Firebase getDisplayName returns null after Redirecting after signup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently making a standard Firebase authentication using the Email provider on AndroidStudio.

I have a simple signup page that prompts for the user's Name, Email, and Password. Once the form is valid, it runs the following code.

**Create User Method**

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                saveUser(email,pass,name);
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(name).build();
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already registered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is the

**saveUser Method**

```
public void saveUser(String email, String password, final String name){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("Email", email);
        data.put("UID",uid);
        data.put("Password",password);
        data.put("Name",name);

        mDatabase.push().setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User stored in DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

For references, here is my ProfileActivity onCreate() method. Basically just displays the User's displayName and a logout button.

**ProfileActivity onCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        logoutBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        profileName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileName);

        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {

                } else {
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        profileName.setText("Welcome, "+ user.getDisplayName()+"!");
    }
```

Right after Signup, the TextView says **"Welcome, null!"**, but when I logout then login with the same account, it displays the proper displayName for the user.

I am quite confused as to what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails to handle the fact that the `onAuthStateChanged` listener is triggered asynchronously. To do this correct, put the code that requires the updated user information **into** `onAuthStateChanged`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    logoutBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
    profileName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileName);

    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                profileName.setText("Welcome, "+ user.getDisplayName()+"!");
            } else {
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, will try this now and will get back to you in a bit.

Comment: I have tried your changes, put the setText **into** the onAuthStateChanged method and I still get the same result. Correct me if I'm wrong but from how I understand it, the user gets automatically logged in after signing up.

Comment: A newly created user is indeed automatically signed in. And that should trigger your `onAuthStateChanged` listener. Does that happen for you? If so, is `user.getDisplayName()` not showing the correct value at this point?

Comment: I am still getting null sadly.

Comment: It seems like this issue is on Firebase's end. Still waiting on an update. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/409